# decide which of the following subsets of $R^3$ are subspace

Tags: vector-spaces

Decide which of the following subsets of $\mathbb R^3$ are subspaces. If it is, verify the properties of a subspace; if it is not, show by example which property fails.

(a) $W= \{x \in \mathbb R^3 \mid x_1 = 2 x_2 \text{ and } x_3 = x_1\}$

(b) $V= \{x \in \mathbb R^3 \mid x_1 = x_2 \text{ or } x_1 = -x_2 \}$

Comment: What's your guess?

Comment: I guess that W is a subspace, and V is not.

Comment: @Kyotomath Wrong, sorry.

Comment: @egreg // Then could you please let me know the correct solution?

Comment: @Kyotomath Both are subspaces. Where are you being stuck at?

Comment: @ egreg // I'm sorry but in (b), "or" should be there, not "and". I have just edited.

Comment: Because (1 1 0 ) + (1 -1 0) = (2 0 0) ∉ V , I guess (b) is not a vector space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both $W$ and $V$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$. In fact, the equations that describes the subspaces are linear and homogeneous.

As first you can see that $0$ belongs to $W$ and $V$. The other properties are  easy to verify. I.e you have to show that taken $v,w$ in $W$ and $a$,$b$ in $\mathbb{R}$, $av+bw \in W$.

Hope to have been useful to you.

Comment: Note that the OP changed the description of $V$.

Comment: Thanks, but because (1 1 0 ) + (1 -1 0) = (2 0 0) ∉ V , I guess (b) is not a vector space. What do you think about it?

Comment: Well, this changes obviously my answer. You have found a  counter-example, so you can say that this is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Sorry, I didn't saw your change.

Comment: @feddy You can edit your answer at any time.

Comment: @egreg thanks, I didn't know.